# Can't retrieve data when using IP address as URL for my web app

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, tomcat

I have a working web application built using the following technologies:
Spring MVC, Java, Hibernate, Oracle Database.

It works fine when I use http://localhost:8080/WebAppName. However, when I use http://:8080/WebAppName, it cannot pull any data. Logs show that there no attempt at all to access the database server.

I tried changing the config of the server.xml in tomcat (as I have found in several questions similar to my problem), such as adding useIPVHosts="true", resolveHosts="true", address="0.0.0.0". All didn't work.

Perhaps there are other configuration files that I need to check/change. Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Below is my hibernate configuration:

```
<bean id="dataSourceDEV1" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource"
    destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@//rac-hr-qa:20001/WBD1" />
    <property name="username" value="workbrain" />
    <property name="password" value="xxxxxxxxxx" />
</bean>
<bean id="sessionFactoryDEV1"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSourceDEV1" />
    <property name="configLocation"
        value="classpath:/com/safeway/web/resources/dev1-hibernate.cfg.xml" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle9Dialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings">false</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="packagesToScan">
        <list>
            <value>com.safeway.web.dao</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="transactionManagerDEV1"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactoryDEV1" />
</bean>
```

```
<hibernate-configuration>

<session-factory>
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">validate</property>
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle9Dialect</property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="connection.pool_size">5</property>
    <property name="temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults">false</property>   
    <property name="hibernate.jdbc.use_get_generated_keys">true</property>
    <mapping class="com.safeway.model.CalculationGroup"></mapping>
    <mapping class="com.safeway.model.CalcGroupVesrion"></mapping>
    <mapping class="com.safeway.model.CalcGroupHistory"></mapping>
</session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: why do you think `http://:8080/WebAppName` would work?

Comment: Oh I'm so sorry...I don't know why the <ip address> there is missing. My original statement was - "However, when I use http://<ip address>:8080/WebAppName, it cannot pull any data. Logs show that there no attempt at all to access the database server."

Answer (score 1):

You need to use an ip address with the **port**.

```
http://:8080/WebAppName
```

should be

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/WebAppName
```

for the IP address of `localhost`.

Comment: Oh I'm so sorry...I don't know why the <ip address> there is missing. My original statement was - "However, when I use http://<ip address>:8080/WebAppName, it cannot pull any data. Logs show that there no attempt at all to access the database server."